# Scenarios for more than one WAR file in an EAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, war, ear

could someone explain me some scenarios where it is a good practice to use more than one WAR file in an EAR project.

Comment: Can somebody at least explain me why I got -1 for this question? Just wondering what did I do wrong :/.

Comment: Ok I found an answer to my question :). Here is the link to question/answer [Multiple war in an ear file](http://www.coderanch.com/t/446575/EJB-JEE/java/Multiple-war-ear-file). Read reply _Why would an ear file have more than one web module?_ from Cameron Wallace McKenzie in that post.

Comment: Hehe, if I am going to continue like this I will be left of any reputation :). Ok, maybe my question was wrong I should have asked in the way Cameron Wallace McKenzie did (_Why would an ear file have more than one web module?_). I will leave this question alone, because I found the answer that I was looking for. The answers in the question _.war vs .ear file_ are for my question (or me) too technical I just wanted to know _When should someone use more than one .war file in an .ear?_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned in comment I found an answer to my question. The answer can be found in the post [Multiple war in an ear file](http://www.coderanch.com/t/446575/EJB-JEE/java/Multiple-war-ear-file) where Cameron Wallace McKenzie gives a possible scenario where multiple war files can be used in an ear file (see post *Why would an ear file have more than one web module?*)